# I want to put multiple versions of jquery in CDN in nuxt

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, nuxt.js

Currently, jQuery 3.1.4 is being externally loaded by CDN on the top page.

index.vue

```
head: {
    bodyAttrs: {
      id: 'overview'
    },
    script: [
      {
        src: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js'
      }
    ]
  }
```

In the lower page, 1.8.3 is included in the CDN because of the jQuery plugin.

**/index.vue

```
head: {
    bodyAttrs: {
      id: 'lower'
    },
    script: [
      {
        src: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js'
      }
    ]
  }
```

Multiple js created with jQuery are put in the assets directory, modularized and imported.
There are some other js files.

ex)~/assets/useragent.js

```
/* global $ */
export default function () {
  // User agent
  var _ua = (function (u) {
    return {
      Tablet: (u.indexOf("windows") != -1 && u.indexOf("touch") != -1 && u.indexOf("tablet pc") == -1) || u.indexOf("ipad") != -1 || (u.indexOf("android") != -1 && u.indexOf("mobile") == -1) || (u.indexOf("firefox") != -1 && u.indexOf("tablet") != -1) || u.indexOf("kindle") != -1 || u.indexOf("silk") != -1 || u.indexOf("playbook") != -1,
      Mobile: (u.indexOf("windows") != -1 && u.indexOf("phone") != -1) || u.indexOf("iphone") != -1 || u.indexOf("ipod") != -1 || (u.indexOf("android") != -1 && u.indexOf("mobile") != -1) || (u.indexOf("firefox") != -1 && u.indexOf("mobile") != -1) || u.indexOf("blackberry") != -1
    }
  })(window.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());

  // Is in viewport
  $.fn.isInViewport = function (screen) {
    var elementTop = $(this).offset().top;
    var elementBottom = elementTop + $(this).outerHeight();

    var viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var viewportBottom = (viewportTop + $(window).height()) * screen;

    return elementBottom > viewportTop && elementTop < viewportBottom;
  };

  $(window).on('load resize scroll', function () {
    $('.shuffle-item--visible').each(function () {
      if ($(this).isInViewport(4)) {
        $(this).addClass('in_viewport');
      } else {
        $(this).removeClass('in_viewport');
      }
    });
  });
}
```

index.vue

```
mounted: function() {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      if (process.browser) {
        JqueryEasing()
        MagnificPopup()
        useragent()
        }
    })
  }
}
```

When I checked it, I added that the following should be described in nuxt.config.js.

nuxt.config.js

```
build: {
    plugins: [
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: 'jquery',
        jQuery: 'jquery',
        'window.$': 'jquery',
        'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
      })
    ]
}
```

When I run npm run dev, I get the following error and it doesn't compile.

```
These dependencies were not found:                    friendly-errors 17:19:16
                                                      friendly-errors 17:19:16
* $ in ./assets/js/useragent.js            friendly-errors 17:19:16
* jQuery in ./plugins/02_jquery.easing.1.3.min.js     friendly-errors 17:19:16
                                                      friendly-errors 17:19:16
To install them, you can run: npm install --save $ jQuery
```

How can I compile separate jQuery versions with a CDN?

After that, I checked it and set it as external so that it is not read in the module

```
build: {
    extend(config, ctx) {
      config.externals = {
        jquery: 'jQuery'
      };
    }
}
```

It can be compiled, but the page is "Cannot find module 'jQuery' from '/ ~'" and cannot be seen.

Comment: i do not see the 1.8.3 version reference here

Comment: I'm sorry, I fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it a solution for the time being from the request for additional / correction to the question? Came to.

1. Make a function that describes the process you want to initialize immediately after loading jquery in methods
2. Register the event with the function beforemonted
3. Make it possible to fire that event in the onload of the head script

After reading jQuety by onload to the script of head method, methods fire

```
head() {
    return {
      bodyAttrs: {
        id: 'photographer'
      },
      script: [
        {
          src:
            'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js',
          async: true,
          onload: this.onJqueryLoad()
        }
      ]
    }
}
```

Enter the methods you want to fire after reading

```
methods: {
    onJqueryLoad() {
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        if (process.browser) {
          JqueryEasing()
        　MagnificPopup()
        　useragent()
        }
      })
    }
}
```

mounted method removed
Others as they are
So it worked.